# Python: strings comparison through several files but found just the last of many possible

Tags: python, regex, string, string-comparison

I am pretty new in Python. I have two kind of files to compare.

The output of the first type - dict.txt - is:

```
1_A
2_B
3_C
```

The output of the second type - 1_1h.txt - is:

```
K
P
A
B
C
E
```

I am trying to make a comparison by isolating with a regex the letter in dict.txt (later I will also use the number next to the letter to know the position/line of the letter itself in the file) and make a comparison of this letter with the letters found in each 1_1h.txt file type.

But I have a problem: it can't recognize all the matching expression but just one.... Why?
In this example there are 2 matches: 'K' and 'C', but the output shows just 'C' and many spaces...
Here is my code:

```
import os
import re
import fileinput

dict_file = open("C:\\Users\\KP\\Desktop\\test\\dict.txt", "r")
dictionary = dict_file.read().split('\n')
#print lines
#print len(lines)
dict_file.close()


for file in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\KP\\Desktop\\test'):
    if file == '1_1h.txt':        
        open(file) 

        for w in dictionary:
            regex = re.compile('(\d)_(.*)')
            res = regex.search(w)
            if res:
               nb_w = int(res.group(1))
               content_w = str(res.group(2))

            for line in fileinput.input(["1_1h.txt"]): 
                print(content_w+"-->"+line)
                if str(line) == str(content_w):
                    print('match '+line)
```

Output:

```
runfile('C:/Users/KP/Desktop/test/testlocale.py', wdir='C:/Users/KP/Desktop/test')
F-->K

F-->J

F-->C
K-->K

K-->J

K-->C
C-->K

C-->J

C-->C
match C
```

Answer (score 0):

`search` only returns one match.

Use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of `search`:

```
res = re.findall('(\d)_(.*)', w)
```

From the docs:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a **list of groups**; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of another match.

```
import os
import re
import fileinput

dict_file = open("C:\\Users\\KP\\Desktop\\test\\dict.txt", "r")
dictionary = dict_file.read().split('\n')
#print lines
#print len(lines)
dict_file.close()

for file in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\KP\\Desktop\\test'):
    if file == '1_1h.txt':        
        open(file) 

        for w in dictionary:
            for nb_w, content_w in  re.findall('(\d)_(.*)', w):
                for line in fileinput.input(["1_1h.txt"]): 
                    print(str(content_w)+"-->"+line)
                    if str(line) == str(content_w):
                        print('match '+line)
```

Comment: Hello and thanks, I got this error

    res = re.findall(w, regex)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 181, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: I still got this error and I don't know how to handle it

`res = re.findall(w, regex) File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 181, in findall return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string) TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: I tried to make a test and it works also without the findall solution... So I think the error is somewhere in the code but I don't know where.

`import re

array = [1, 2, 3]
array_2 = ["0_a", "2_b", "4_c", "3_d"]

for i in range(0, len(array)):
    for k in range(0, len(array_2)):
        regex = re.compile('(\d)_(.*)')
        res = regex.search(array_2[k])
        nb_w = int(res.group(1))
        
        if array[i] == nb_w:
            print "match "+str(array[i])`


Output:
`match 2
match 3`

Comment: edited, try now. you need the pattern not the compiled regex, my bad

Comment: another error : 
`File "C:/Users/KP/Desktop/test/test4loop.py", line 29, in <module>
    nb_w = int(res.group(1))-1
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94088/discussion-between-jurafsky-and-sebastian-wozny).

Answer (score 0):

Find the error: it can be found while reading the

```
file = '1_1h.txt'
```

Its output was not simply read as:

```
K
P
A
B
C
E
```

but - I don't know why - it was read as:

```
K

P

A

B

C

E
```

For this reason even if I had for example A B C in my dictionary file I was able to recognize just C as matching word in my file 1_1h.txt because it was the only one without the '\n'

That's finally my code:

```
import os
import re
import fileinput
import numpy as np

matrix = np.zeros(shape=(10,10))


dict_file = open("C:\\Users\\KP\\Desktop\\test\\dict.txt", "r")
dictionary = dict_file.read().split('\n')
dict_file.close()


for file in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\KP\\Desktop\\test'):
    if file == '1_1h.txt':
        regex = re.compile('(\d)_(.*)')
        res = regex.search(file)
        if res:
            nb_file = int(res.group(1))-1 

        filename = file
        #if os.path.isfile(file):
        open(file) 
        for line in fileinput.input([filename]):
            line = line.replace("\n", "")
            for w in dictionary:
                test = w.split('_',1)            
                if line == test[1]:
                    print nb_file                    
                    print test[0]
                    print str(line)+" "+test[1]
                    print '####'
                    matrix[nb_file,test[0]] = 1


print matrix
```

Output:

```
runfile('C:/Users/KP/Desktop/test/test4loop.py', wdir='C:/Users/KP/Desktop/test')
0
1
A A
####
0
2
B B
####
0
3
C C
####
[[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```